# Reading the link text from PHP code

Tags: php, html

In my PHP application there is a link which generate total summary data. Now I need to add another link which generates current date summary data rather than total summary.

I created the link and got the query to do the same. Now the challenge is to identify which link is clicked in the function. Is there any way I can get the clicked link text from php code? So that I can differentiate between them and call the appropriate branch of code can be executed.

Comment: Please provide a code sample.

Comment: how exactly can you *not* know what link was clicked?

Comment: go learn how to pass variables with POST and GET examples in forms/php

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_GET` to differenciate which link was clicked.

in your HTML, make the links like this:

```
<a href='my_page.php?report_id=1'>Report 1</a>
<a href='my_page.php?report_id=2'>Report 2</a>
```

In your PHP file (in the example above, it is `my_page.php`) it should have something like:

```
<?php

   if (isset($_GET['report_id']) {
     $report_id = $_GET['report_id'];
     if ($report_id =='1') {
         // ... generate the first report here
     }
     else if ($report_id=='2') {
         // ... do the other stuff here
     }
   }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly whay I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the links direct to different pages one page for total summary one for daily or you could put the info in the URL of the link for instance

```
<a href="path.php?daily_report=true>Generate daily<\a>
<a href="path.php?total_report=true>Generate total<\a>
```

Post your code if that doesn't help

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need it to be in one page.